# How to shorten thread name in logback logs?

Tags: java, logging, logback

You can shorten the name of the logger using %logger{x} syntax where x controls shortening procedure. Is there any way to shorten the name of the thread the same way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
[%.7thread]
```

This will print the *last* 7 characters of the thread name.

Trailing characters of a thread name are often more interesting than the characters at the beginning of a thread name. :-)

You may read about the [maximum field width modifier](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#formatModifiers) in the logback docs.

Comment: I just opened a new feature request for %thread{length}. http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-813

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
[%.-10t]
```

This expression prints the first 10 chars of the thread name.

Answer (score 6):

To print the 7 last characters and Rightpad with spaces:

```
[%-7.7thread]
```

Output:

```
14:22:43.097 [main   ] DEBUG 
14:22:43.341 [main   ] INFO  
14:22:43.341 [main   ] INFO  
14:22:45.399 [-target] INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is the equivalent of the `{x}` syntax for `%thread`, but you can use something like `%.-5thread` to print just the first 5 characters of the thread name, but just 5, not a shortened version (obviously, adjust the number to your needs).

Answer (score 1):

What about this at your thread's beginings?

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().split("-").length > 1) {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    threadName = "thread" + threadName.split("-")[3];
    Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
}
```

Then in your logback.xml:

```
[%-8thread] %msg%n
```

... and you'll get something like this:

```
[main    ] Process started
[thread1 ] Thread started
[thread2 ] Thread started
[thread1 ] Thread ended
[thread1 ] Thread started
[thread2 ] Thread ended
[thread2 ] Thread started
[thread1 ] Thread ended
[thread2 ] Thread ended
[thread3 ] Thread ended
[thread4 ] Thread ended
[thread5 ] Thread ended
[main    ] Process ended
```