# JavaFX Piece Movement Not Updating Immediately in Board Game

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I’m developing a board game in JavaFX where a player can move a piece and then an AI bot makes its move. The game is designed such that when the human player releases a piece at any point on a valid square then the piece will automatically be snapped to the center of the square. However, I’m experiencing an issue where the piece’s position isn’t updated on the UI until after the bot finishes its move decision.

Here’s a simplified version of my code:

```java
pieceComp.getEllipse().setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
    // Process the move
    int newRow = toBoardPos(pieceComp.getLayoutY());
    int newCol = toBoardPos(pieceComp.getLayoutX());
    Move move = new Move(game.getBoard()[oldRow][oldCol], game.getBoard()[newRow][newCol]);
    MoveResult moveResult = game.processMove(move);

    if (moveResult.isValidMove()) {
        pieceComp.move(newRow, newCol); // this is where the piece is relocated
        switchPlayer();
        if (game.getCurrentPlayer() instanceof BotPlayer) {
            new Thread(() -> Platform.runLater(this::botMakeMove)).start();
        }
    } else {
        pieceComp.abortMove();
    }
});
```

In the `botMakeMove()` method, the bot decides its move which takes about 2-3 seconds. I’ve tried running `botMakeMove()` on a separate thread to prevent it from blocking the UI thread, but the issue persists.

I have also ensured that there are no other long-running or blocking operations happening on the UI thread.

I’ve also checked that `pieceComp.move(newRow, newCol);` is being called before `botMakeMove()`, but its UI changes aren’t appearing until after `botMakeMove()` finishes.

Any insights into why the piece’s position isn’t updating immediately, and how I can resolve this issue?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the botMakeMove() method would also update the UI (as the bot makes its move)

Comment: *” I’ve tried running botMakeMove() on a separate thread to prevent it from blocking the UI thread”*. Show your attempt to do that. The code in the post runs `botMakeMove()` on the UI thread.

Comment: @James_D I have shown that in the code:
`new Thread(() -> Platform.runLater(this::botMakeMove)).start();`
The new thread executes the Platform.runLater() which I was hoping to solve the problem. Please notice me if you need further details.

Comment: @VũHoàng, you do understand that code that is run in `Platform.runLater` is run on the JavaFX thread.

Comment: @SedJ601 yes I do my expectation is after the piece's position is updated then the bot move would be executed. I forgot to mention that the botMakeMove() method would also update the UI (as the bot makes its move).

Comment: So, the way your code is written, the `Thread` is useless. You should use `Task`. Do the bot thinking in the `Task` and use the `Task's` `onFinished` to do the actual move.

Comment: As others have pointed out, `Platform.runLater(…)` executes the provided runnable on the FX Application Thread and returns immediately. You’re assuming that the UI would be rendered between the end of execution of your event handler and the execution of the provided runnable; this is not guaranteed by the API and is generally very unlikely to happen, as the JavaFX framework will throttle rendering of the UI to a maximum of 60 times per second. Delegating the calculation of the move to a background thread, and displaying the result on the FX thread using a task is the way to do this, as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved: Delay in UI Update When Moving Piece in JavaFX Board Game.

I managed to resolve the issue with a great suggestion from @SedJ601.

The solution was to use a javafx.concurrent.Task to run the bot’s decision-making process on a separate thread. This allowed the UI to update immediately after the player’s move, while the bot’s move was being decided.

Here’s the modified botMakeMove() method:

```java
private void botMakeMove() {
    // Create a new Task
    Task<Move> botMoveTask = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected Move call() {
            // Perform the long-running operation (bot deciding its move)
            BotPlayer botPlayer = (BotPlayer) game.getCurrentPlayer();
            Move botMove = botPlayer.getBestMove((GameWithBot) game);
            return botMove;
        }
    };

    // Set up what to do when the Task is done
    botMoveTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        // Get the result of the Task
        Move botMove = botMoveTask.getValue();

        // Update the UI according to the bot's move...
        switchPlayer();
    });

    // Start the Task on a new Thread
    new Thread(botMoveTask).start();
}
```

This approach ensures that the bot’s decision-making process doesn’t block the UI thread, allowing the piece to snap to its position immediately when released, even though the bot is still deciding its move.

I hope this helps anyone else who’s facing a similar issue!

Comment: I would consider setting up a single-threaded `Executor` so that you're reusing a single thread instead of creating a new one each time. For example, using Java 21+, `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(Thread.ofPlatform().daemon().factory())`. Note you would create the executor once and save a reference to it somewhere.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to [uniquely name any threads you create](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.Builder.OfPlatform.html#name(java.lang.String)). `Thread.ofPlatform().daemon().name("ai-", 0).factory())`. Then, if you [log the thread name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924112/how-to-shorten-thread-name-in-logback-logs) anywhere, the log context shows your named thread and number, which can be useful to check the sequence of thread execution, that things are executing on the expected thread and how many threads you are creating.